# Z-index does not work between 2 react functional components

Tags: css, reactjs, components, z-index

Here is my example where I need to put the first component in front of the second.
Currently the second component is in front of the first despite z-index. I tried also to put style on the component tag but it does not work. Where is my mistake ?

First component:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 500px;
z-index: 100;
`;

function Aaa() {

    return (
        <Container>asd</Container>
    )
}

export default Aaa;
```

Second component

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 500px;
margin-top: -200px;
background: pink;
z-index: 1;
`;

function Bbb() {

    return (
        <Container>qwe</Container>
    )
}

export default Bbb;
```

App:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Aaa />
    <Bbb />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `position: relative`.

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

E.g.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 500px;
margin-top: -200px;
background: pink;
z-index: 1;
`;

function Bbb() {

    return (
        <Container>qwe</Container>
    )
}

export default Bbb;
```

Comment: just added it and it does not work again. Btw I knew this and forgot to add on my example but I tried it before and it just dont want to work...

Comment: `position` was the missing point for me :) Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a container for the components instead of fragment and apply display: flex and flex-direction: column on that container and see if it works. Edit: Code sandbox with fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-frog-fie10?file=/src/Aaa.js

Comment: tried like this and it does not work again ....: 

<div style={{position: 'relative', zIndex: 1, display: 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'column'}}>
      <Aaa />
      <Bbb />
    </div>

Comment: probably it something from react's component... This is weird problem..

Comment: You need to add position: absolute to the components for z-index to work. Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-frog-fie10?file=/src/Aaa.js. Please note that when you use position relative, the elements will never be on top of each other, even if you apply negative margin.

Comment: thats it Abhish Abraham !!! This is the mistake - the negative margin is the problem ! The example is working very well but I have to have something on top of my relative component which have to be absolute and then if it is out of my base it will be on top of the another component ! Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it not work,this seems no reason.But what ever, maybe you could use this instead:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
const Container = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    `;

    function Aaa() {

    return (
        <Container>asd</Container>
    )
    }

    export default Aaa;
```

Comment: nothing changed with this. Whats the point here? My point is to make just visual transition effect between 2 sections of my page., Thats why I need to overlap the sections.

Comment: your code could work well.
Just see it by the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-clarke-gnpy7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are right Hidden, its ok. I see now I just forgot to put background color in order to see it is working good.... Thank you !

Comment: your are welcome